# retrieving latest post from Tumblr via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm trying to integrate a Tumblr blog into a website. Specifically I want to display the latest text post.

I have taken a look of Tumblr API and everything looks quite easy but I cannot make it work.

According to the documentation for Tumblr API v2  (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)
this is the call I need:

http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=KEY&limit=1
and if I put it in my browser I get what I want.

However if I try to retrieve the post'title to it using jquery 1.7.1 as specified below

```
$.getJSON('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=<KEY>&limit=1', function(data) {
  console.log("data.posts[0].title");
});
```

I get an empty response.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

SIG

Comment: its checking for Authorized Context/Cookie... are you actually Logged In/Authenticated to get response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) as of the [Same-Origin-Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

How to do this you can read in the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) in the *Response Format* section.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. At the end I was able to make it work     I have added $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=KEY&limit=1&jsonp=parseResponse",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      timeout : 10000
  });  and defined a parseResponse function that does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Andreas is worked for me. I changed the code with $.ajax and data type to JSONP. Now I am able to get the data from tumblr.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=<KEY>&limit=1",               
    dataType: "JSONP",
    success: SuccessCallbackFunction,
    error: ErrorCallbackFunction,
});
```